# Laravel inserting into a three-way pivot table

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, tags, pivot-table

### Summary

I am building a music discovery service. My question is: **How do I insert data into the three-way pivot table** *Tag_Track_User* **?**

### Schema

I have this schema seen [here at LaravelSD](http://www.laravelsd.com/share/WNmzz8)

It comprises of six main tables (and a few others):
**Artists, Albums, Tracks, Tags, Users and Tag_Track_User**

[image: Schema]

The **Artists->Albums->Tracks** relationship is straightforward and as you'd expect.

**Tags, Tracks and Users** all relate to one-another as **no two can exist without the third**.

### Relationships

**Artists** *hasMany()* **Albums**

**Albums** *hasMany()* **Tracks** and *belongsTo()* an **Artist**

**Tracks** *belongsTo()* **Albums**

**Tracks** *belongsToMany()* **Tags** and *belongsToMany()* an **Users**

**Tags** *belongsToMany()* **Tracks** and *belongsToMany()* an **Users**

**Users** *belongsToMany()* **Tags** and *belongsToMany()* an **Tracks**

### Models

**User model**

```
public function tags()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Tag', 'tag_track_user', 'user_mdbid', 'tag_mdbid')->withPivot('track_mdbid');
}

/**
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
 */
public function tracks()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Track', 'tag_track_user', 'user_mdbid', 'track_mdbid')->withPivot('tag_mdbid');
}
```

The **Tag** and **Track** model contain the same respective relationships.

### Question

So my question is:

How do I insert data into the *Tag_Track_User* table? The *tag_track_user* table is a 3-way pivot table cointaining information about tracks that users have tagged.

You have to be logged in to tag a track (which means I have access to the user’s ID). The tracks ID is accessed as I am displaying it on the page where the form is contained. The tag on the other hand; if it already exists in the tags table, I want to get it’s ID and re-use that (as they are unique), if not, I want to create it, assign it an ID and insert that into the tag_track_user_table.

1. I need to check whether the *Tag* exists
2. If it does, get it's ID
3. Insert data into the *Tag_Track_User* table

### Thank you

Any help I receive on this, is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It could be something like `$tag->tracks()->attach($track->mdbid, ['user_mdbid' => Auth::user()->mdbid]);`, I haven't tested the construct for a multidimensional array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well:

```
$tag = Tag::firstOrCreate(array('text' => $tag_text));

TagTrackUser::create(array(
    "tag_mdbid" => $tag->mdbid,
    "track_mdbid" => $track->mdbid,
    "user_mdbid" => Auth::user()->mdbid
));
```

Something like that? `firstOrCreate` does what the name says it does, the rest is pretty straightforward Eloquent.

Comment: TagTrackUser isn't a model? Should it be? Or... Doesn't it need to be?

Comment: It's a model according to that LaravelSD link you posted. I hit EXPORT ALL -> MODEL and got TagTrackUser.php :)

Comment: LaravelSD generates everything automatically. It isn't a model though.

Comment: Well then just use `DB::table('tag_track_user')->insert(array(...));`

Answer (score 1):

Since seems that there is not an appropriate pattern in Laravel, the cleaner and easier way is to implement any three-pivot-relationships via a model dedicated to the pivot table:

```
class Track
public function trackTags()
{
    return $this->hasMany('TagTrack');
}

...
class Tag
public function tagTracks()
{
    return $this->hasMany('TagTrack');
}

...
class TagTrack
public function track()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Track');
}
public function tag()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Tag');
}
public function anotherRelationship(){
...
}
```

You can do:

```
$track->trackTags->myCustomPivotDataAndRelationship()
```

and in TagTrack you have freedom to add as many relationship and field I want

Note than you can still keep the many to many to use when you don't need to access pivot relationships